# Write-only mapping a O_WRONLY opened file supposed to work?

Tags: linux, mmap

Is `mmap()` supposed to be able to create a write-only mapping of a `O_WRONLY` opened file?

I am asking because following fails on a Linux 4.0.4 x86-64 system (`strace` log):

```
mkdir("test", 0700)          = 0
open("test/foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
ftruncate(3, 11)                        = 0
mmap(NULL, 11, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The `errno` equals `EACCESS`.

Replacing the open-flag `O_WRONLY` with `O_RDWR` yields a successful mapping.

The Linux `mmap` man page documents the errno as:

> ```
>    EACCES A  file descriptor refers to a non-regular file.  Or a file map‐
>           ping was  requested,  but  fd  is  not  open  for  reading.   Or
>           MAP_SHARED  was  requested  and PROT_WRITE is set, but fd is not
>           open in read/write (O_RDWR) mode.  Or PROT_WRITE is set, but the
>           file is append-only.
> ```

Thus, that behaviour is documented with the second sentence.

But what is the reason behind it?

Is it allowed by POSIX?

Is it a kernel or a library limitation? (On a quick glance, I couldn't find anything obvious in `Linux/mm/mmap.c`)

Comment: I think it isn't even logical to map a file O_WRONLY. After all, how could you possibly write to a write-only page? The OS first has to read in a complete page worth of the file's contents (or the zero page, on behalf of the file, if you created it anew or extended it) before you can write the first byte into it. Thus, without reading, there can be no writing (not with memory mapping anyway). If reading is forbidden, this is bound to fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [*IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition* (POSIX.1 2004)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) appears to forbid it.

> An implementation may permit accesses other than those specified by `prot`; however, if the Memory Protection option is supported, the implementation shall not permit a write to succeed where `PROT_WRITE` has not been set or shall not permit any access where `PROT_NONE` alone has been set. The implementation shall support at least the following values of `prot`: `PROT_NONE`, `PROT_READ`, `PROT_WRITE`, and the bitwise-inclusive OR of `PROT_READ` and `PROT_WRITE`. If the Memory Protection option is not supported, the result of any access that conflicts with the specified protection is undefined. **The file descriptor `fildes` shall have been opened with read permission, regardless of the protection options specified**. If `PROT_WRITE` is specified, the application shall ensure that it has opened the file descriptor `fildes` with write permission unless `MAP_PRIVATE` is specified in the `flags` parameter as described below.

*(emphasis added)*

Also, on x86, it is not possible to have write-only memory, and this is a limitation of the page table entries. Pages may be marked read-only or read-write and independently may be executable or non-executable, but cannot be write-only. Moreover the man-page for `mprotect()` says:

> Whether `PROT_EXEC` has any effect different from `PROT_READ` is architecture- and kernel version-dependent. On some hardware architectures (e.g., i386), `PROT_WRITE` implies `PROT_READ`.

This being the case, you've opened a file descriptor without read access, but `mmap()` would be bypassing the `O_WRONLY` by giving you `PROT_READ` rights. Instead, it will refuse outright with `EACCESS`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think the x86 hardware supports write-only pages, so write access implies read.  But it seems to be a more general requirement than just x86 - `mm/mmap.c` contains this code in `do_mmap_pgoff()`:

```
    case MAP_SHARED:
        if ((prot&PROT_WRITE) && !(file->f_mode&FMODE_WRITE))
            return -EACCES;
        ....
        /* fall through */
    case MAP_PRIVATE:
        if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_READ))
            return -EACCES;
```

I think that explains what you're seeing.