# Mmaping shell-opened stdout

Tags: c, linux, permissions, posix, file-descriptor

Shells open redirected stdout with `O_WRONLY`. Such files cannot be `mmap`ed ([Write-only mapping a O_WRONLY opened file supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014515/write-only-mapping-a-o-wronly-opened-file-supposed-to-work)). Is there a work-around for this? Can I reopen the same filedescriptor (i.e., `1` == `STDOUT_FILENO`) but with `O_RDWR` without knowing a/the name of the file?

Comment: For mmap() to succeed, the file must be seekable. Stdin/stdout streams are not. `mmap()` will probably return (void*)-1/ENODEV

Comment: @wildplasser I'm trying to `mmap` stdout redirected to a seekable file (`./a.out > some_file`). So far it looks like only Linux has a solution -- opening `/proc/self/fd/1` with `O_RDWR`.

Comment: The file *may* be seekable, but it starts with size=zero. You may have to periodically (after write) call `mremap()`

Comment: @mremap I'm doing `ftruncate` before the `mmap`.

Comment: @wildplasser Stdin/stdout are just as seekable as any other file handle. It all depends on what they're connected to.