# Why memory mapping to `STDOUT_FILENO` failed?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I have written some code to test the `mmap` system call.

Here I want to map the virtual memory address space to the `STDOUT`, and print a string via the pointer `ptr` that returned by the `mmap`.

```c
int main()
{
    void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, STDOUT_FILENO, 0);
    memcpy(ptr, "hello", 6);
}
```

But this code failed:

```sh
$ gcc mmap.c
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And I have tested `mmap` on `STDIN`, it is ok.

```c
int main()
{
    // executed by `./a.out < text.txt`
    void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, STDIN_FILENO, 0);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, ptr, 1024); 
}
```

Why `mmap` on `STDOUT` failed here? And what are the differences between `mmap` on `STDIN` and `STDOUT` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, when you use services, check the error codes to narrow down the problem.
Re-writing your program as follow:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, STDOUT_FILENO, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == ptr) {
      fprintf(stderr, "mmap(): error '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
      return 1;
    } else {
      memcpy(ptr, "hello", 6);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program displays the following:

```
$ ./a.out
mmap(): error 'No such device' (19)
```

That is to say that you get the *ENODEV* error code. Looking at the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), you get the following explanation:

> ENODEV The underlying filesystem of the specified file does not support memory mapping.

Actually, the file descriptor is pointing on the terminal device driver and the latter does not allow the  `mmap()` operation.

Concerning the second program mapping *STDIN_FILENO*, when you run it like that:

```
$ ./a.out < text.txt
```

The preceding makes *STDIN_FILENO* "point" on the *text.txt* file, not the input terminal. Hence, `mmap()` works here...

So, with the same idea, we expect that the first program works with:

```
$ ./a.out > foo.txt
```

Since the output is no longer a terminal but a file. But you get the *EACCES* error:

```
$ ./a.out > foo.txt
mmap(): error 'Permission denied' (13)
```

The answer is explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014515/write-only-mapping-a-o-wronly-opened-file-supposed-to-work). A file must be opened with the *read* access to be mapped but the standard output of a program launched by the shell is opened *O_WRONLY*. Hence, the `mmap()` fails. Under Linux, it is possible to use a trick. The file descriptors are symbolic links in */proc/pid/fd* directory. So, it is possible to reopen the file pointed by the symbolic link */proc/pid/fd/1* with *O_RDWR* flag and use the famous `close()/dup()` trick to make the file descriptor number 1 (*STDOUT_FILENO*) point on this newly opened file. A call to `ftruncate()` is necessary to reserve space in the file and *MAP_SHARED* flag is required to make visible the modifications to other processes (e.g. the shell when the program terminates):

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    char symlink[256];
    int fd;

    snprintf(symlink, sizeof(symlink), "/proc/%d/fd/1", getpid());
    fd = open(symlink, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen(): error '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
      return 1;
    }
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);
    ftruncate(STDOUT_FILENO, 1024);
    void *ptr = mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, STDOUT_FILENO, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == ptr) {
      fprintf(stderr, "mmap(%d): error '%m' (%d)\n", fd, errno);
      return 1;
    } else {
      memcpy(ptr, "hello", 6);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hence, you get what you expect:

```
$ ./a.out
mmap(3`): error 'No such device' (19) # The output is the terminal (mmap() forbidden)
$ ./a.out > foo.txt   # The output is a file
$ cat foo.txt
hello$
```

Comment: *the famous close()/dup() trick* That introduces a race condition.  There's no guarantee that the new file descriptor value will be the same - another thread or even a signal handler - as all of `open()`, `pipe()`, `openat()`, and `pipe()` are async-signal safe and can be used in a signal handler - could open a file and "steal" the file descriptor value.

Comment: [Use `dup2()` instead](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html): "The `dup2()` function shall cause the file descriptor `fildes2` to refer to the same open file description as the file descriptor `fildes` and to share any locks, and shall return `fildes2`. If `fildes2` is already a valid open file descriptor, it shall be closed first"

Answer (score 2):

The difference is not *stdin* vs *stdout*

It is between a regular disk file descriptor and some pseudo-tty file descriptor. See [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (more precisely `fstat`) and [inode(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html).

As regular file (of type `S_IFREG`) can be [lseek(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)-ed and the Linux kernel is doing some equivalent when fetching a virtual memory page with `mmap`.

A socket or pseudo-tty cannot be `lseek`-ed.

You could try `echo foo | a.out`  and it will also fail, since a [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) cannot be `lseek`-ed.

Of course, you should read the documentation of [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). It can fail, and you should use [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) or [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) on failure.

So code instead:

```
void *ptr = 
   mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, 
        MAP_PRIVATE, STDIN_FILENO, 0);
if (ptr == MMAP_FAILED) 
   { perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Try also [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on existing command-line programs to learn more about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)